# is it possible to deny access to an app to my input devices which i have installed through `sudo apt-get install`?

Tags: apt, software-installation, permissions, security, monitoring

the company i am working for has made me install an **employee monitoring app** on my **personal laptop** which I have installed via `sudo apt-get install` command. I come to know that the app can take screenshots, recording of my screens without my consent any time. So i want that app to stop taking those screenshots, screen recordings without asking me first.

Is there any way to prevent that app to take those. may be i can setup some kind of password before that? or write some kind of script?

Comment: Not without risking the wrath of the company, if it's a Condition of Employment. Screenshots, etc., are saved with timestamps,. If any are missing, it will be noticeable.  Sounds like you're trying to violate a "use it only for work" agreement,  which, depending,  could be a criminal act, or avcorporate policy violation, leading to termination. Are you *sure* you want to work there? Aren't you paid enough to buy a cheap computer?

Comment: You could `dpkg -L` on the package to see what files it has, run `strings` and `ldd` on the  executable, but just look, don't touch.

Comment: @waltinator. it is my personal laptop. so employer understood the concern and didn't force me to do after uninstalled that. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is specifically a personal laptop, you can dual-boot or create a VM Guest to house the monitored work environment.

Use that dedicated, monitored work environment only for work. Shut it down when not in use.

- DON'T create a VM Guest for your personal-use environment. A monitor application on the Host will be able to see that.
- Were this an employer-provided laptop, the advice would be very different. Never (never!) alter employer-provided hardware nor software without clear, written permission of the owner.

Comment: i removed that software from my system and told employer citing privacy concern. he didn't force me after that. thanks